# CloudFormation Refer to old stack to retrieve Instance ID's to create backup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ami

Scenario : If i already have a cloudformation stack(A) that has 5 instances that it deployed, Can I create a new Cloudformation stack (B) that will reference the first stack (A) to retrieve instance ID's to create a back up (Create Image [AMI])?

I only know how to launch the first stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cross-stack reference in Stack B to retrieve instance IDs from the outputs of Stack A.  [Here is a little tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-crossstackref.html) on how to do this.